# Change Format Time AM / PM to 24 hour Timeline Day fullcalendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-scheduler

I have a project user jQuery fullcalendar-scheduler, I want to format time to use 24 hour. I have config as below, but it didn't work. Is there something wrong with my code ??

```
{
        now: moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD'),
        contentHeight: setUpHeight(),
        aspectRatio: 1.8,
        header: {
            left: 'today prev,next',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'timelineDay,timelineMonth'
        },
        timeFormat: 'H(:mm)',
        defaultView: 'timelineDay',
        resourceLabelText: 'Devices',
        resources: resources,
        events: schedules,
        eventRender: function (event, el) {
            el.qtip({
                content: {
                    delay: 1e3,
                    text: function () {
                        return $('#qtip-content-custom').html(event.description);
                    },
                },
                style: { classes: 'qtip__clases' },
                position: {
                    target: 'mouse',
                    adjust: { x: 7, y: 5 }
                },
            });
        }
}
```

And the result still use AM / PM, like this :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OBmtO.png)

Comment: If an answer below has solved your question, please accept it by clicking the green arrow. If not, feel free to create your own answer to your question. Your question, however, should not also contain your resolution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**SOLUTION:** Just add [`views`](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/view-specific-options) option like this :

```
views: {
  timelineDay: {
    slotLabelFormat: ['H:mm'],
  },
  timelineMonth: {
    slotLabelFormat: ['DD'],
  },
},
```

Answer (score 3):

Try [`slotLabelFormat`](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/timeline/slotLabelFormat/).

e.g.

```
slotLabelFormat: ['H:mm']
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this work for me when i set day mode. But when i use month mode label column look like this 

https://drive.google.com/drive/u/0/folders/17KxHyVpcGOq_VUBXOb88JCP_R4HlBLDe

how can i set when the month mode label column use the days back ??

Comment: Thanks this problem has been solved.. the way i update on above.

Answer (score 0):

Change this :

```
timeFormat: 'H(:mm)',
```

by :

```
slotLabelFormat:"HH:mm",
```

Answer (score 0):

version for 3.9.0 in fullcalender.js inside to globalDefaults :

```
maxTime: "24:00:00",
slotLabelFormat: ['H:mm'],
```